# Problems with JavaScript Dropdown Nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a JavaScript drop down navigation menu that I found after some Googling and I've managed to style it the way I want.  However, after validating my site, I get errors with the `ul` tags (Error: Element `ul` not allowed as child of element `ul` in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)).  Not only do I get this error, the navigation doesn't work the way it should.  I've tried different variations of the `ul` and `li` tags, and moved things around, and I still cannot get it to work correctly.

```
<div class="nav">
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <ul>

    <li class="submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
            </li>

    <li class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul> 
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li class="submenu"><li><a href="#">Deny</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="noborder"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul> 
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <ul>

    <li class="submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Four</a>
        <ul>

    <li class="submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you replicate your code in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The ul in Two > Deny is not properly nested.

Comment: please write your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: The JS doesn't appear to work with it for some reason. http://jsfiddle.net/Km9Z6/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is this is the problem with your java script code. But the mismatch in writing of these html tags also may cause these kind of problems. Please check the opening and closing tags once again and make sure those are in the correct position or not. When i gone through your html code i found some mismatch in the tags. One is- 
your **FIRST** menu item **Two** are written in between two li /li tags. But your FIRST **One** menu item are **NOT** in between these li /li tags.

Answer (score 1):

Close your parent div tag and see if that helps

also this...

```
 <li class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </ul>
    </li>
```

...probably needs re-work because you are nesting an li tag before creating a child ul tag. You just to need to learn how to properly nest ul and li tags.  Here is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265718/wrong-example-of-nested-ul-li-on-very-well-known-web-design-tutorial-site) I found on stackoverflow that talks about a similar issue.

Once you get your HTML correct, the javascript process should be easier to manage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have completely rewritten the whole navigation making sure that I closed tags as I opened them to be on the safe side.  Thank you for your help!